# Verification of this CMOS realisation

Tags: cmos, verification

I have to make the CMOS-equivalent of this function: \$A'*B'+C'\$. I made this CMOS-circuit, but I'm not sure if it's correct:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPIEZv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The course I'm following isn't very clear about this subject.

Comment: What part of it are you not sure about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ′ means that the signal is inverted then it is fine.